# Fill program in C

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program in C that, given the user's input of a character boarder for a shape, fills the shape in.

http://pastebin.com/aax1dt0b

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "simpio.h"
#include "genlib.h"

#define size 100

bool initArray(bool a[size][size]);
bool getshape(bool a[size][size]); /* Gets the input of the boarder of the shape from         the user */
void fill(int x, int y, bool a[size][size]); /* fills the shape */
void printarray(bool a[size][size]); /* prints the filled shape */


main()
{
    int x, y;
    char i;
    bool a[size][size];
    initArray(a);
    getshape(a);
    printf("Enter the coordinates of the point the shape should be filled.\n");
    printf("x=n\n"); /* gets the coordinates of the array to begin the fill algorithm from */
    x = GetInteger();
    printf("y=\n");
    y = GetInteger();
    fill(x, y, a);
    printarray(a);
    printf("Scroll up to view your filled shape\n");
    getchar();
}

bool initArray(bool a[size][size])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = FALSE;
        }
    }
}

bool getshape(bool a[size][size])
{
    int i, j, k;
    bool flag;
    char ch;
    ch = 1;
    printf("Enter your shape. When you are finished, type 'E'. \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
    {
        flag = TRUE;
        for (j = 0; ch != 10; j++)
        {
            ch = getchar();
            if (ch == 69)
            {
                return a;
            }
            if (ch != 32) a[i][j] = TRUE;
        }

        ch = 1;
    }
}


void fill(int x, int y, bool a[size][size])
{
    if (a[y][x] != TRUE) a[y][x] = TRUE;
    if (a[y][x - 1] != TRUE) fill(x - 1, y, a);
    if (a[y - 1][x] != TRUE) fill(x, y - 1, a);
    if (a[y][x + 1] != TRUE) fill(x + 1, y, a);
    if (a[y + 1][x] != TRUE) fill(x, y + 1, a);
}

void printarray(bool a[size][size])
{
    int i, j;
    printf("\n\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] == FALSE) printf(" ");
            if (a[i][j] == TRUE) printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

My program works for the most part, but when it prints the filled shape, it adds one additional character to each row. For example, if the user's input it

```
    ***
    * *
    ***
```

Then the output will be

```
****
****
****  (one extra row then it should be)
```

whereas it should be

```
***
***
***
```

anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: In other words, show your code.

Comment: Added the code, sorry about that.

Comment: No not in pastebin, add it to the post and use the `{}` to format it.

Comment: This isn't  homework. And added the code to the body.

Comment: FYI the `initArray` method can be replaced by `bool a[100][100] = {{FALSE}};`.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are several potential problems in your code, I'm going to just identifying the problem of the 4th column *'s. In the code below, although you're checking `ch!=10` in the `for statement`, the value of `a[i][j]` is getting assigned `TRUE` before terminating the loop. So you might want to do `if(ch!=32 && ch!=10) a[i][j]=TRUE;`.

```
                     flag=TRUE;
                     for(j=0;ch!=10;j++)
                     {
                                      ch=getchar();
                                      if(ch==69)
                                      {
                                                return a;
                                      }
                                      if(ch!=32) a[i][j]=TRUE;
                     }

                     ch=1;
```